# Noun + da kara desu -- why are da and desu mixed? why not both "da" or both "desu"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, politeness, copula

In this sentence:

> *Neko da kara desu.*
>   Because it's a cat.

Why are the "da" and "desu" used at the same time? Logically, it should've been:

> *Neko desu kara desu.*

Or in a casual conversation if we don't drop the last "da":

> *Neko da kara da.*

Right?

Comment: "neko da kara desu" is "it's because it's a cat".   Ignoring the issue of formality, your question is essentially the same as asking why in English we have "it's" in there twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the casual form is ～だからだ and its polite form is ～だからです. e.g.

> ネコだからだ(よ)。
>   人間だからです。
>   坊やだからさ。

The から is a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle), definition #1 in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/45491/meaning/m0u/):

> 2⃣ [接助]活用語の終止形に付く。 １ 理由・原因を表す。「もう遅い**から**帰ろう」
>   (attached to the predicative form of 活用語. 1. indicates a reason or cause.)

The から needs to be attached to the predicative form such as ～だ or ～する, so here you get ねこだから (not *ねこから), then you use a copula だ or です to end a sentence (though you can just say ～だから。 in casual conversation), so you say ねこだからだ or ねこだからです.

You don't say *ねこですからです because you wouldn't need more than one polite marker in one clause, I think...

Comment: `because you wouldn't need more than one polite marker in one clause, I think...
` -- it's not clear for you?

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty that that's the reason... but at least, I can say that we don't repeat です or ます in one phrase like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those funny nuance things. It's got little to do with grammar and more to do with how it **feels** to say that. If I wanted to sound condescending I'd say it like that, though I guess to get that effect tone of voice is also important.

You would never in a million years say desukara desu. That just doesn't work. 9 times out of 10 you would just say neko dakara. Nothing more.

Comment: I know. My question is why.